# Notifications have black and white colors - why are they both colors?

Tags: nexus-7, notification-bar, color

Currently as of Android 5.0.1 update my Nexus 7 2013 shows black and white notifications. I see no logic in the colors and it does not really look very good as well. Why is that? Is this a bug? Intention? If intention, what is it showing?

And while we are at it, what is the line that separates the notifications? The weather one is persistent and so is twilight, so it does not separate persistent notifications.

[image]

Comment: Is the first notification (weather) and the second notification (33m) from the same app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The colour**

I believe the background colour of each notification depends on the app that added it, I think the default is white for 'stock' Android.

**The line**

This is to separate the different levels of priority for notifications. I expect the Twilight one is set to lowest priority (`MIN`) whereas the weather one will likely have a higher priority (`MAX`). Whilst some apps do allow you to specify the priority, most will just set what the believe to be most appropriate. Google does provide [guidelines](https://developer.android.com/design/patterns/notifications.html#how_to_choose_an_appropriate_priority) on how to choose the appropriate priority to help developers in this regard.

Comment: It is strange that weather is considered as of highest priority...

Comment: So as I understand you, you believe, that the first two notifications explicitly set the background color of their rectangles to black? I mean, in the former android versions notification had no option in changing the notification rectangle color (not that I know of or ever seen any). So I would expect that by default old unmodified apps would have the color of the rectangle holding the notification default - which now seems to be white (or at least google now and twilight has it white)

Comment: It is/was [possible](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#CustomNotification) to change the background colour in previous versions of Android so it's not something that would have changed in Android 5.0.

Comment: So you are saying that the first two notifications probably set a non-default layout for the notification, which makes them non-default-white but black? That may actually be possible. In that case thank you for the answer. As of the line, I still do not know if the important ones are supposed to be up or down and why one weather is up and one is down. It still may be that weather bug has set a default "important" priority and is up even though it should be down by new logic.

Comment: @Ev0oD I still remember Google Now sets its notification to minimum priority since KitKat... at least that's what I believe.